# HTTP Content-Disposition Header

Tags: ajax, http, pdf, http-headers

I am making a successful AJAX POST request and in the response headers are the fields `content-disposition: inline; filename="report.pdf"` and `content-type: application/pdf`. From what I understand about these headers I expect the browser to display the PDF once the response is received, however the response comes back and nothing happens. Am I misunderstanding how these headers work? Am I missing a step that needs to be taken once the response is received by the browser?

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "https://externalAPI.com" ,
          contentType: "application/json",
          data: payload,
          headers: {"Authorization" : "XXXXXXXXX"}
        })
```

I've started up a test server so that I can mess with the response headers and see if I can get anything to work. `Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="pleasework.pdf"` is also not working, not prompt for a file download. Here are my full response headers:

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
 Connection:keep-alive
 Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="pleasework.pdf"
 Content-Type:application/pdf
 Date:Wed, 15 Jul 2015 15:14:39 GMT
 File-Extension:pdf
 Number-Of-Pages:1
 Transfer-Encoding:chunked
 Vary:Origin
 X-Powered-By:Express
 X-XSS-Protection:0
```

Comment: Please add some of your code

Comment: does `content-disposition: attachment; filename="report.pdf"` work?

Comment: This is a post to an external API, so I am unable to edit the response headers. Just wondering if I am missing something that should be done once I receive the response.

Comment: Any chance you don't have adobe or some other pdf reader plugin enabled in the browser you're testing on?